# What is the most "database independent" way of creating a variable length text field in a database

Tags: sql, database, jdbc

I want to create a text field in the database, with no specific size (it will store text of length unknown in some case) - the particular text are serialized simple object (~ JSON)

What is the most database independent way to do this :
- a varchar with no size specified (don't think all db support this)
- a 'text' field, this seems to be common, but I don't believe it's a standard
- a blob or other object of that kind ?
- a varchar of a a very large size (that's inefficient and wastes disk space probably)
- Other ?

I'm using JDBC, but I'd like to use something that is supported in most DB (oracle, mysql, postgresql, derby, HSQL, H2 etc...)

Thanks.

Comment: if you're having trouble on this, what happens when you start doing queries with dates and time, anything with row numbers, or fancy query tuning techniques??  if you are just writing serialized simple object look at flat files.

Comment: Most "basic" types would be stored int the proper database type (Number-> BIGINT, String -> varchar) etc...
Only the 'other' types would be serialized into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a varchar of a a very large size (that's inefficient and wastes disk space probably)

That's gonna be the most portable option.  Limit yourself to 2000 characters and you should be fine for most databases (oracle being the current 2000 limiter, but be wary of *old* mysql versions as well).  I wouldn't worry too much about disk space, either.  Most databases only use disk for the actual data saved in the field.

Answer (score 3):

Do you *really* need to support all six of those databases? (hint: **No.**)

I've come to the opinion that writing universally portable SQL DDL is not worth the trouble.  [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

You should support the databases you are *currently* using, and be prepared to adapt to a database that you adopt in the future.

---

Re your comment:  The only standard SQL variable-length data types are `VARCHAR` and `BLOB`.  `VARCHAR` is for string data and its declaration includes a character set and collation.  `BLOB` is for binary data and does not support charset/collation.

Other data types such as `VARCHAR(max)`, `CLOB`, or `TEXT` are vendor extensions:

- `VARCHAR(max)`: [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)
- `NVARCHAR(max)`: [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)
- `LONGVARCHAR`: [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefsqlj15147.html), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#N10497)
- `CLOB`: [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefclob.html), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#N10497), [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
- `NCLOB`: [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm)
- `TEXT`: [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
- `NTEXT`: [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Do I need all those myself -> No.
But since the code is part of an API, and i don't want to tell the end user they have to use a particular DB, the more 'compatible' the better ... although i know SQL implementation are all over the places.
That's why I'm asking for the "most" database independent of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BLOB. JDBC2.0 API supports it and so any driver that supports JDBC2.0 (J2SE 5.0 on) should support it.
The advantages of BLOB are :
1. Size can be as large as 4G-1 (Oracle. other databases not so sure)
2. Can store any data you wish (even images serialized into some field in your JSON structure)
3. Completely neutral to transport across OS
4. You can still take advantage of indexes on keys that reference the BLOB so that searches on ids etc, don;t have to be done by getting at the structure.

Comment: I just see that JDBC also support CLOB, that might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework like hibernate, so you won't have the problem to find a universal solution. I don't think that you can use one universal type in every mentioned database. The databases differ to much, I guess.

Comment: Well what I'm actually writing is sort of a basic ORM (like a basic hibernate), for a new language that does not have any yet ... I'm trying to stay away from having DB vendor specific code ... but might be forced to.

Answer (score 0):

[text is perhaps best](http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Data+types+of+attributes+in+the+DBMS,) but to be removed shortly from SQL Server and there is *no* DBMS independent option for *all* you listed.

Saying that, portability is overrated when it comes to SQL. You're more likely to change your client code before you change DBMS. Pick one and go with that....